# How can I turn a Node.js http.IncomingMessage into a Fetch Request object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to work with the eBay APIs.  It's a small personal project that just needs to run locally, and although I know C#, I'm much more comfortable with Javascript so I'm looking for ways to get this done in JS.

I found this promising looking [eBay Node API with browser support](https://github.com/hendt/ebay-api). Browser support is something I'm looking for, but it [also says that](https://github.com/hendt/ebay-api#browser)

> A Proxy server is required to use the API in the Browser.

They give [an example file for a proxy server](https://github.com/hendt/ebay-api/blob/master/proxy/worker.js) that is a Cloudflare worker.

I'm trying to translate that into something I can run in Node locally using the basic Node HTTP server.  I've been following through it and am doing OK so far, figured out the different ways to access the headers and check them, etc., but now I'm at the point where the proxy server is making the proxy request to the eBay APIs.  The way the example file is set up, it seems as though the Cloudflare worker intercepts the HTTP request and by default treats it as a Fetch `Request`.  So then when it goes to pass on the request, it just kind of clones it (but is replacing the headers with "cleaned" headers):

```
// "recHeaders" is an object that is _most_ of the original
// request headers, with a few cleaned out, and "fetchUrl"
// is the true intended URL to query at eBay

const newReq = new Request(event.request, {
    "headers": recHeaders
});

const response = await fetch(encodeURI(fetchUrl), newReq);
```

The problem is that I don't have a Fetch `Request` to clone - since I'm running a Node HTTP server, what is `event.request` in the example code is for me a [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).

So how can I turn that into a Fetch `Request`?  I'm guessing at the *very least* there's stuff in the message body that needs to get passed along, if not other properties I'm not even aware of...

I don't mind doing the work, i.e. reading the stream to pull out the body, and then putting that into the `Request` object somehow (or do I even need to do that? Can I just pipe the stream from the `IncomingMessage` directly into a `Request` somehow?), but what else besides the body do I need to make sure I get from the `IncomingMessage` to put into the `Request`?

How do I turn a Node `http.IncomingMessage` into a Fetch `Request` and be sure to include all relevant parts?

Comment: Just leaving this here:

https://github.com/withastro/astro/blob/2dca81bf2174cd5c27cb63cb0ae081ea2a1ac771/packages/integrations/vercel/src/serverless/request-transform.ts#L2

Astro took this from SvelteKit. Just requires you to install set-cookie-parser:

`npm i set-cookie-parser && npm i -D @types/set-cookie-parser`. Then you get a Web Fetch API Request using get_request.

You can also set a ServerMessage's data from a Web Fetch API Response using set_response

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple function to convert.

```
const convertIncomingMessageToRequest = (req: ExpressRequest): Request => {
  var headers = new Headers();
  for (var key in req.headers) {
    if (req.headers[key]) headers.append(key, req.headers[key] as string);
  }
  let request = new Request(req.url, {
    method: req.method,
    body: req.method === 'POST' ? req.body : null,
    headers,
  })
  return request
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to try to convert something of type `ExpressRequest`, and what I am dealing with is of type [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage).  For instance, my `req` object does not have a `.body` property.

Comment: ExpressRequest in this case is just an express request that have node IncomingMessage type. What my example shows is to create a new Request and “populate” it with stuff that you need. But I read it again and realize you don’t really know what is in the original request to/from ebay, so this may complicate things and I don’t know how to help.